# Python error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when trying to loop over list

Tags: python, list, set

I am trying to loop over a string list, skip the first two strings, and then replace `1` with `''` in the remaining strings in the list.

```
stringList = {['abc', 'def', 'ghi1', 'jkl1']}
xx = [col.replace('1', '') for col in stringList if col not in stringList[1:2]]
print(xx)
```

My code throws this error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I want `xx` to equal a list of: `'ghi'`, `'jkl'`

How can I do this?

Comment: You are putting a list in a set: `{['abc', 'def', 'ghi1', 'jkl1']}`. You can't do that, because a list is not hashable, and sets require all contents to be hashable. Why are you using both `{..}` (sets and dictionaries) and `[..]` (lists) there?

Comment: In other words, the next line is never reached. The traceback would have told you this.

Comment: Wow, how silly of me, I complete ignored the curly's were there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Python, sets must contain elements that are hashable (see [Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)). A list is not hashable, but a tuple is. If it still serves your purpose, you can use a tuple instead of a list:

```
stringList = {('abc', 'def', 'ghi1', 'jkl1')}
```

You should try to read the error messages more carefully. The error trace would have told you which line was causing the error. Additionally, the message itself is complaining about lists, of which there are only 2 in your example.

Comment: The OP seems to expect a list with strings, not a set with a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The below code prints `['ghi', 'jkl']`

Is that what you wanted?

```
stringList = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi1', 'jkl1']
xx = [col.replace('1', '') for col in stringList if col not in stringList[0:2]]
print(xx)
```

As Martijn Pieters said in the comment, you are putting a list `['abc', 'def', 'ghi1', 'jkl1']` inside of a set.

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.
>   Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a
>   sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection,
>   union, difference, and symmetric difference.

[Python Set Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset)